# Detect Mathematica operators eg. \[CircleTimes] in strings

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to detect all Mathematica operators/symbols (eg.  [CircleTimes], [Colon], etc.) in strings so I can replace them with something else, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Wouldn't `StringReplace` do this job ?

Comment: Not at first sight, but thanks to you I've got another idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly match specific operators as:

```
 s = "abc\[CircleTimes]def"
 StringReplace[s, "\[CircleTimes]" -> "CircleTimes"]
```

> "abcCircleTimesdef"

It seems not too unreasonable to manually create a list of all the operators you need to handle.

this builds a list of rules for every possible "\[..]" character

```
allspecial = (#[[1]] -> StringTake[#[[2]], {4, -3}]) & /@ 
   Select[ Table[ {#, ToString@FullForm@#} &@
          FromCharacterCode[i] , {i, 65535}] , 
            StringMatchQ[ #[[2]], "\"\\[" ~~ ___ ~~ "]\""] &];
s = "abc\[CircleTimes]def\[ScriptCapitalX]ghi"
StringReplace[s, allspecial]
```

> "abcCircleTimesdefScriptCapitalXghi"

Comment: I need to replace all the \[ScriptCapitalX] letters as well (X can be any letter). So this is not perfect as well.

Comment: OMG, this is it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@"\[CircleTimes]", ("\\[" ~~ Shortest[c__] ~~ "]") :> c]
```

but there's a drawback - FullForm changes the string also in other places, for instance where a slash "\" exists, so another solution would be welcomed...